# CSS Carousel/Slide Animation through elements of an array

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I have data being sent from my backend to my frontend and then the data is parsed and displayed into a table. However, at it's max amount of elements in the array, there are too many rows in the table and it exceeds the area that I need the table to be in. So a carousel/slide animation would be the best bet and I want to be able to display elements 4 rows at a time and then invoke the slide animation the the next 4. I'm not quite sure how to do this in the current iteration of my function that sets the table data. 
Can someone point me in the right direction?

```
function FormTable(props){
    /**
     * props = allStations
     */
   console.log(props.data)
    return(
        <table className="form__table">
            <div className="form__table-parentDiv">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th className="form__table-header">Departing Station</th>
                        <th className="form__table-header">Arriving Station</th>
                        <th colSpan={2} className="form__table-header">Departure Time</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    {
                        props.data.map( (stationIndex) => {
                            // console.log(stationIndex);
                            let cells = [];

                            for(let i = 1; i < stationIndex.length; i++){
                                cells.push(
                                    <React.Fragment>
                                        <td className="form__table-stations"> {stationIndex[i].station} </td>
                                        <td className="form__table-stations"> {stationIndex[i].destination} </td>
                                        <td className="form__table-arrivals"> {stationIndex[i].firstArrival} </td>
                                        <td className="form__table-arrivals">  {stationIndex[i].secondArrival} </td>
                                    </React.Fragment>
                                );
                            }

                            return <tr className="form__table-row" >{ cells }</tr>
                        })
                    }


                </tbody>
            </div>

        </table>
    )
}
```

Comment: why is there a `console.log(props.data)` in the return of your render? thats not jsx...

Comment: @JohnRuddell it was a way for me to confirm that data that was coming was correct

Comment: Yes, you can use a console.log. just dont do it in the `return` of your `render` function.

Comment: @JohnRuddell thanks for the heads up. I have fixed it